# How to dynamically add xml element to a java JAXRS representation?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

Say I have a java class that is a representation of a "Dog" with attrbutes "Color" and "Type" marked up with `@XmlElement` and `@XmlRootElement` tags. How do I add a "Age" xml element to this JAXRS based class programmatically without modifying my Dog class with `@XmlAttribute(name="Age")`?

Assume I have the representation:

```
DogRepClass adog = new DogRepClass();
```

Comment: Where is the age attribute's value defined in your model in the first place?

Comment: For xml it would be like:

<Dog><color>Brown</color><type>German Shepherd</type><age>5</age></Dog>

Comment: No, I meant how is it supposed to be represented in `DogRepClass`?

Comment: Normally it would be @XmlElement(name="age") public String age;

Comment: But I don't _want_ “normally”! I want to know what the non-standard model is that you're using this time. If you can just add the annotation, its a trivial normal use of JAXB. What I want to know is where the information is going to be coming from if adding an extra annotation is unacceptable; it's got to be somewhere and the detail matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own MessageBodyWriter (http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) only for this particular type. It can marshall your instance into DOM, modify it and serialize afterwards. Not nice nor elegant, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create your own `MessageBodyWriter` but rather than make your own from scratch, you can extend it to process some custom annotations that your message body writer can recognize via the `.entity(Object, Annotation[])` method.  That way you just add on something specific for your needs